# Validating Saml Response From OneLogin

Tags: c#, .net, saml, onelogin

I'm trying to validate a Saml Response from OneLogin and am running into an intermittent issue. It seems that when the GUID value in InResponseTo begins with a number, validation of the token fails with an exception message: ID4128: The value is not a valid SAML ID. Parameter name: value. However, when the GUID begins with a letter, the token is parsed successfully.

My code:

```
 public Saml2SecurityToken GetToken(string token)
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(token);
        var assertionList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Assertion", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");

        var handlers = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers;
        var securityTokenXml = assertionList[0].OuterXml;

        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(securityTokenXml))
        {
            using (var xmlreader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
            {
                return (Saml2SecurityToken) handlers.ReadToken(xmlreader);
            }
        }
    }
```

My token:

```
<saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.0" ID="pfx74145d78-55a9-dd78-00a0-2ee76d06a900" IssueInstant="2017-12-04T17:46:32Z">
<saml:Issuer>https://app.onelogin.com/saml/123</saml:Issuer>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
        <ds:Reference URI="#pfx74145d78-55a9-dd78-00a0-2ee76d06a900">
            <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <ds:DigestValue>111</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>abc...</ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>abc...</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<saml:Subject>
    <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">nameHere</saml:NameID>
    <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
        <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2017-12-04T17:49:32Z" Recipient="http://localhost/" InResponseTo="7ee0ebbd-3827-4e53-adc5-b8ec35917f2d" />
    </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
</saml:Subject>
<saml:Conditions NotBefore="2017-12-04T17:43:32Z" NotOnOrAfter="2017-12-04T17:49:32Z">
    <saml:AudienceRestriction>
        <saml:Audience>AudienceName</saml:Audience>
    </saml:AudienceRestriction>
</saml:Conditions>
<saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2017-12-04T17:46:31Z" SessionNotOnOrAfter="2017-12-05T17:46:32Z" SessionIndex="_fd124dd0-bb48-0135-5d75-0a8402be19a0">
    <saml:AuthnContext>
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </saml:AuthnContext>
</saml:AuthnStatement>
```

Full Stack Trace:

```
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2Id..ctor(String value)
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadSubjectConfirmationData(XmlReader reader)
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadSubjectConfirmationData(XmlReader reader)
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadSubjectConfirmation(XmlReader reader)
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadSubject(XmlReader reader)
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadAssertion(XmlReader reader)
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2SecurityTokenHandler.ReadToken(XmlReader reader)
at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.ReadToken(XmlReader reader)
```

Is there another way to read/validate this? Or can the InResponseTo be ignored/removed somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If OneLogin is sending unsolicted responses with IDs that start with a number, then they are not compliant with spec. IDs are of the [xsd:ID](http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_ID.html) datatype and have a specific definition: it must start with a letter or underscore, and can only contain letters, digits, underscores, hyphens, and periods.

However, looking at this, they are sending that in the InResponseTo field... Which is the ID **you** sent them in your AuthnRequest... So, you need to fix your code, because they are being nice and just accepting what you sent them. You certainly should fix this so you're compliant.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I am sending a GUID as Id in my AuthRequest. Changing how my Id is created fixes the problem.